# Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(1-2^{1/n})$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that the following sum converges: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(1-2^{1/n}).$$

The terms of the sequences are increasing , and $\lim(1-2^{\frac{1}{n}})=0.$

So I don't think I'll be able to use alternating series test.

So how do I proceed?

Comment: I've edited the question according to what I think is the correct interpretation. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizCriterion.html

Answer (score 1):

Leibniz test since $(2^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)$ tend to zero and is decreasing and $(-1)^{n-1}$ have bounded sum

Answer (score 1):

You can  rewrite your series as: 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(1-2^{1/n})=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(2^{1/n}-1),$$
and now the general term decreases.